# Задать шаблон, по которому ищется слово

Tags: регулярные-выражения

подскажите пожалуйста

Есть шаблон в стиле "a3b1n1", и мне нужно найти слово в тексте, где встречается слово имеющее 3 буквы a, 1 букву b, 1 букву n. Пример искомого слова: banana

Comment: n встречается 2 раза

Comment: @entithat эт врядли. aaabn

Comment: @entithat, нет) это же по порядку будет идти, а нужно именно на вхождение в слове в любом порядке. Можно ли сделать это проще или нужно именно разбивать каждое слово насимволы и проверять их количество

Comment: разбивать и считать, вероятно быстрее, но можно и через regex - в ответте написал

Comment: @splash58, ой, да-да. Забыл что-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться Lookahead

```
\b(?=(?:\w*a){3}\w*\b)(?=(?:\w*n){2}\w*\b).+?\b
```

\w - ищет латинские буквы, цифры ии подчеркивание. Если в `слове` могут присутствовать другие символы, надо поменять на нужный набор

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/JhVPvK/1)

Comment: нет к сожалению, слово то мы ищем в тексте. Получается ерунда какая то

Comment: Поменяйте начало и конец строки на обратный слэш b

Comment: увы, нет.

может проблема в том, что я не совсем верно высказался, но мне нужно найти абсолютно все слова в тексте которые подходят под данный шаблон

а тут получается что он сам текст находит, если есть такое слово

Comment: Изменил ответ. посмотрите

Comment: да, именно то, что искал) большое спсибо)